# MVVM Listbox Update Content Maintain Selected Item Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, binding, listbox, command

I've been reading a lot about MVVM (using Laurent Bugnion's library in specific) and I'm constantly struggling to determine how to do things in MVVM that were otherwise easy with code behind.

Here's just one example where I suspect I'm doing things the hard way.  If anyone has the time to read all this, perhaps they can comment on the sanity of my approach. :)

I have a list box bound to a ViewModel like so:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstFruitBasketLeft" ItemsSource="{Binding FruitBasket}" 
     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFruit, Mode=TwoWay}"  Width="150">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            <TextBlock Text=":" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Quantity}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

The ItemSource is an ObservableCollection of Fruit objects:

```
public class Fruit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public Fruit() { }
    public Fruit(string name, int quantity) 
    {
      this.Name = name;
      this.Quantity = quantity;
    }
  }
```

It is defined in the ViewModel as:

```
// Property FruitBasket
public const string FruitBasketPropertyName = "FruitBasket";
private ObservableCollection<Fruit> _fruitBasket = null;
public ObservableCollection<Fruit> FruitBasket
{
  get { return _fruitBasket; }
  set
  {
    if (_fruitBasket == value)
      return;

    _fruitBasket = value;

    // Update bindings, no broadcast
    RaisePropertyChanged(FruitBasketPropertyName);
  }
}
```

The bound SelectedItem property is as such:

```
//Property SelectedFruit
public const string SelectedFruitPropertyName = "SelectedFruit";

private Fruit _selectedFruit = null;

public Fruit SelectedFruit
{
  get { return _selectedFruit; }
  set
  {
    if (_selectedFruit == value)
      return;

    var oldValue = _selectedFruit;
    _selectedFruit = value;

    // Update bindings, no broadcast
    RaisePropertyChanged(SelectedFruitPropertyName);
  }
}
```

Then, the list is populated on the construction of the ViewModel.

Now, I add a RelayCommand to a button on the presentation page that executes a method which increments the quantity of the selected item.  Note that I am not using the parameter yet, but "Bob" is a placeholder for some changes for later.

```
<Button x:Name="butMore" Content="More!" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="25" Width="75" Margin="4">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <cmd:EventToCommand
                Command="{Binding addMoreCommand}"
                CommandParameter="Bob" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Here's the code for the command:

```
// Property addMoreCommand
public RelayCommand addMoreCommand
{
  get;
  private set;
}
```

...

```
  //Init relays (this is in the constructor)
  addMoreCommand = new RelayCommand(AddFruit, CanExecute);
```

...

```
public void AddFruit()
{
  //Increment the fruit
  SelectedFruit.Quantity++;

  //Save the previous selected item
  Fruit oldSelectedItem = SelectedFruit;

  //We have to have a new list in order to get the list box to refresh
  FruitBasket = new ObservableCollection<Fruit>(FruitBasket);

  //Reselect
  SelectedFruit = oldSelectedItem;
}


public bool CanExecute()
{
  return true; //for now
}
```

Now this does work, but I have some problems with it:

First, I feel like there are a lot of conditions that have to come together for this to work and I wonder if I'll get so lucky trying to move some Telerik Drag and Drop code into MVVM.

Second, it seems like a pretty poor performance approach to recreate the list like that.

Lastly, it seems like this would be easier in code behind (though I'm not 100% certain I still won't have to rebuild that list).

Does anyone have any thoughts on my approach or perhaps even... suggestions to make things easier?  Am I just missing something obvious here?

Thanks

-Driodilate :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maulkye,

There is something going wrong if you have to refresh your `ObservableCollection`. Usually, you should not need it because the `ObservableCollection` will notify about item changes.

Never do this:

```
FruitBasket = new ObservableCollection<Fruit>(FruitBasket);
```

Your `public ObservableCollection<Fruit> FruitBasket` should have **no public setter**, it should be read only. Just `Add` or `Remove` Items to/from the list.

If you want to handle multiple selections, you will probably need an extended `CollectionView` which can handle this, get more hints [here](http://grokys.blogspot.com/2010/07/mvvm-and-multiple-selection-part-iii.html).

I hope this helps a little bit, even if I probably didn't answer all questions : )

**EDIT:**
Ok, I guess i got some things wrong. Now i guess i fully understand what you're trying to accomplish. You are **not** getting notified when your property is changed, right? Well, for this reason, we've adapted "[BindableLinq](http://bindablelinq.codeplex.com)" in one of our projects, which you can compile in Silverlight without problems. (there are similar solutions available, called [Continuous Linq](http://clinq.codeplex.com/) or [Obtics](http://obtics.codeplex.com/), make your choice).

Using **BindableLinq**, you can transform your `ObservableCollection` to a `BindableCollection` using one single extension method. The `BindableCollection` will then reflect all changes properly. Give it a try.

**EDIT2:**
To implement a **proper** ViewModel, Please consider the following Changes.

1) `Fruit` is your **Model**. Since it doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, it won't propagate any changes. Create a `FruitViewModel`, embedding your `Fruit` Model and invoke `RaisePropertyChanged` for each property setter.

2) Change your `FruitBasket` to be an `ObservableCollection` of `FruitViewModel`. Slowly it starts to make sense :)

3) `SelectedFruit` has to be a `FruitViewModel` as well. Now it makes even more sense.

4) Now it already works for me, even without `BindableLinq`. Did you have any success?

HTH

best regards,
thomas

Comment: Well, that does help, but it leaves me in the situation of not knowing how to get the bound control to update properly. Bear in mind that I am not adding or removing items (that works perfectly without the extra code). My problem occurs when I'm updating a property on one of the objects that is in the ObservableCollection.

Comment: Hmmmm, though you got me thinking.  I could just remove the selected item, update it, and then add it back to get the automatic updates to work.  Although I'm not sure how that will impact sorting.

Comment: Check my EDIT, there is another track you could follow :)

Comment: I'll have to spend some more time looking at these. My first test with Bindable Linq compiled and ran, but didn't propagate my changes (I did compile the source into my project since it was targeted at WPF in it's project).  Also, if I do get it working, I'm not sure just yet how to push it into my ViewModel.  I'll comment once I've had some more time with it.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok ok, yeah you're talking about ViewModels, right, please check my EDIT2 and forget `BindableLinq` first. Maybe we'll come back to it later but you need to implement a proper ViewModel first

Comment: YA! That worked. Thank you so much for your time and help Thomas. I really didn't expect to get so much assistance with such a long initial post. (I marked this as the answer, but my account doesn't have enough rep to vote the post up yet :( )

Comment: I understand why this now works, but it sort of contradicts my initial understanding of MVVM. I thought you just made a VM for each view... not for each model. Is it typical to have a VM for each model, or just in cases like this that demand it? Thanks again!